# What would be an efficient way to check duplicate answer in the following case?

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

I am trying to solve this problem in leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/

```
public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) 
{
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(candidates);        
    helper(candidates, target, res, new ArrayList<>(), 0);        
    return res;
} 
private void helper (int[] candidates, int target, List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> temp, int index) {
    if( target < 0) return;
    if(target == 0) {
        res.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        return;
    }

    for(int i = index; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        if(candidates[i] > target) {
            return;
        }

        temp.add(candidates[i]);
        helper(candidates, target - candidates[i], res, temp, index);
        temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
    }
}

For an input: candidates = [2,3,6,7], and target = 7
My output is: [[2,2,3],[2,3,2],[3,2,2],[7]]
Correct Output: [[2,2,3],[7]]
```

Obviously, I need to check for a duplicate before adding to the result.

I understand I can create a set of strings where each string will be a sorted version of the list e.g., [2,3,2] => "223". This will help me to check whether I need to add the list to the result or not.

**My question is what would be the best way to check for a duplicate in my situation?**

Comment: why do you need the best one? And what is your definition of best? Fastest? Using less memory? The one that look the most elegant? Why is the solution you already found not good enough?

Comment: this problem is similar to coin change problem....have a look.

Comment: @Wisthler You raise a valid concern. I was not clear enough in my question what was the answer I am looking for. Basically, I was looking for an answer which gives some criticism to the way I am thinking and also another way to do the same. 

Specifically, I was looking for a discussion of the tradeoff between time and space while doing the same thing different way. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *best* means, but you can use [Collection.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
public static Set<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target)
{
--->>    Set<List<Integer>> res = new HashSet<>();
    Arrays.sort(candidates);
    helper(candidates, target, res, new ArrayList<>(), 0);
    return res;
}

private static void helper(int[] candidates, int target, Set<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> temp, int index) {
    if( target < 0) return;
    if(target == 0) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newRes = new ArrayList<>(temp);
--->>        Collections.sort(newRes);

        res.add(newRes);
        return;
    }

    for(int i = index; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        if(candidates[i] > target) {
            return;
        }

        temp.add(candidates[i]);
        helper(candidates, target - candidates[i], res, temp, index);
        temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

**Input**

candidates = [2,3,6,7], and target = 7

**Output**

[[2, 2, 3], [7]]

Comment: My bad. I was not clear enough in my question what was the answer I am looking for. Basically, I was looking for an answer which gives some criticism of the way I am thinking and also another way to do the same. Specifically, I was looking for a discussion of the tradeoff between time and space while doing the same thing a different way. :-)

Answer (score 3):

By adding the following lines in your helper method would do the expected result.

```
if(target == 0 ) {
    Collections.sort(temp); // This will sort your list, that you want to add
    if(!res.contains(temp)) // Check if sorted list already existing in your result list or not. Only add the temp list if it does not exist in your res list.
        res.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
    return;
}
```

or else you can also add the elements in sorted order in your `res` list and then use HashSet to remove the duplicates from your `res` list.

```
 Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>(res);
 res.clear();
 res.addAll(set);
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible alternative approach to avoid duplicates entirely (without having to explicitly check for them) would be as follows:

Instead of looping through every element in the for loop in your helper function (note that the index parameter is always same in your recursive calls), you can think of the solution as follows:

1. Either you consider the element at given index, and recurse again with the same index(thus being able to consider the same element multiple times) OR
2. You don't consider the current element, and recurse with index+1.

This way you wouldn't end up getting duplicates in your solution.

Not posting the entire solution here (don't want to rob you of all the fun :P ), but the recursive steps in the helper function would essentially be:

```
# don't consider element at index, and increment index in recursive call
self.helper(candidates, target, index+1, res, temp) 

# consider element at index `index`
self.helper(candidates, target-candidates[index], index, res, temp+[candidates[index]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate for not giving me the code, I changed my code and got the intended outcome.

I am accepting a previous comment just because they address the problem of dealing with "duplicate" while you solved the problem without actually checking of the duplicate. :-)

Comment: as a matter of fact, finding a way to eliminate completly the duplicates is solving your issue as effectively as the accepted answer. And that's the ideal solution in term of performance, memory usage and elegance :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a Set for this. You could instead just sort both your Arrays using `Arrays.sort()` an then check for equality over all indexes, e.g. like this:

```
public Boolean isEqual(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    if (a1.length != a2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    Arrays.sort(a2);
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Apply this for your result and keep the Arrays results that return `false`.